# How to declare webview ownership in google play console?

Tags: android, webview, google-play, android-webview, google-apps

My android app is build by adding whole webview of my web application which I want to mainly launch for android users not for browser based users. But I get my app suspended from google play store review team. Reason being that they have no proper information about ownership of my webview content. I just want to know that how to prove that my webview content is under my ownership.

Comment: [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746)

Answer (score 4):

After so much exploring I understand how we can prevent webview application to be not suspended by Google.

1st your website should be verified by Google Search console.
2nd Provide advance notice to the Google Play App Review team. [LINK](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/contact/adv_note)

If you done above 2 step, there is strong possibility that your app will accepted by google play store.

3rd If possible you should not just add webview only, try to add first splash screen or use some native android activities. Because Webview is not build for converting website into application. It gives you feature to add website in your android application, so by considering in mind, develop and publish your application.

Good luck

Answer (score 1):

I've never had success with webview. I've did some investigation a long time ago and I found that RSS, Webview and other kind of content channels (Youtube videos) are a prohibited ways on Play Store since It is made for people who want to publish their apps and not their websites.

Till date, google have no interest to allow explicit use of webview by verifying ownership.

But if you want further information about how you can leverage that without getting flagged or suspended, the best way is to ask them directly on their email.