# Proof Azure Website Ownership to Google Play

Tags: azure, dns, google-play, azure-web-app-service

My problem is similar [to this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51594727/how-to-declare-webview-ownership-in-google-play-console). But I need to make one step further.

I whant to publish [my website](https://sobopedia.azurewebsites.net/) webview on google play. Google Play have rejected my submission but after I send them a email they respond and said that they will allow app publication if I send them pdf with distribution agreement, authorization contract, website domain information or something like that prooving my website ownership. My website hosted on [azure](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/). I have domain name like xxxxx.azurewebsites.net. Please help me to understand how can I make pdf document that prooves my website owership.

Will be very greatfull for help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, about how to verify your Azure Website ownership, you can refer to these Google documents as below.

1. [Handling Android App Links](https://developer.android.google.cn/training/app-links/)

   > Secure and specific: Android App Links use HTTP URLs that link to a website domain you own, so no other app can use your links. One of the requirements for Android App Links is that you verify ownership of your domain through one of our website association methods.

   and

   > Add verification for your deep links: Configure your app to request verification of app links. Then, publish a Digital Asset Links JSON file on your websites to verify ownership through Google Search Console. Learn more in [Verify App Links](https://developer.android.google.cn/training/app-links/verify-site-associations).
2. [Verify Android App Links](https://developer.android.google.cn/training/app-links/verify-site-associations)

   > To verify ownership of both your app and your website, the following steps are required:
   >
   > - Request automatic app link verification in your manifest. This signals to the Android system that it should verify your app belongs to the URL domain used in your intent filters.
   > - Declare the relationship between your website and your intent filters by hosting a Digital Asset Links JSON file at the following location:
   >     https://domain.name/.well-known/assetlinks.json
3. The section `Verify your website` of [`App Indexing on Google Search`](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6041489?hl=en) in Play Console Help introduces the steps

   > 1. Sign in to your Play Console.
   > 2. Click All Applications All applications.
   > 3. Select the application you'd like to verify.
   > 4. On the left menu, click Development tools > Services & APIs.
   > 5. Under "App Indexing from Google Search," click Verify website.
   > 6. Type your website address.
   > 7. Click Verify.
   > 8. Go to Google Search Console.
   > 9. On the left menu, click All Messages.
   > 10. Open the verification request message (example: "Google Play: Link http://www.yourwebsite.com to android-app://example.com.yourpackage.name").
   > 11. Click Approve the request.
   > 12. Review the information and click Approve. Once approved, your app will appear on the
   >       Search Console Home Page for your account. Be sure that your app enables deep links.

If you have a Google Search Console account or not, here is two links of `Verify your site ownership` of Search Console Help for [old](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/35179?hl=en) and [new](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/9008080?hl=en) Search Console will be helpful.

> **Tip**: Only Google Search Console users with "Owner" permissions can view and approve site verification requests. If you don't see your site verification request, make sure you're signed in using an account with "Owner" permissions.

Second, the `xxxx.azurewebsits.net` is just a [subdomain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subdomain) of `azurewebsites.net` which be registed by Azure and you can lookup the related info via `https://www.whois.net/` as the figure below, so it's not belong to you.

[image]

Therefore, you need to register a domain name like `abc.com` in the Domain Name Registrar like GoDaddy or others, and add a [`CNAME`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CNAME_record) record with it into DNS server like [Azure DNS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dns/dns-operations-recordsets-portal), then to follow the above steps required by Google to verify your website ownership and collect the necessary information to make a PDF document to send to Google.

Comment: Thank youy very much for such a detailed answer! I have been following the third step and now my app is published.